# Проблема с делегатами и событиями в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, observer

Не могу разобраться как использовать делегаты и события в проекте Unity.
У меня есть класс Observer

```
public class Observer : MonoBehaviour 
{

   #region Singletone
   private static Observer _instance;
   public static Observer Instance
   {
       get
       {
           if (!_instance)
           {
               _instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof(Observer)) as Observer;
               if (_instance == null)
               {
                   Debug.Log("Error!");
               }
           }
           return _instance;
       }
   }
   #endregion

   public delegate void GivePoints(int value);
   public static event GivePoints OnGivePoints; 
}
```

У меня есть метод Death в скрипте зомби:

```
public void Death()
{
    if (Observer.OnGivePoints != null)
    {
        Observer.Instance.OnGivePoints(5);
    }
}
public void GivePoints(int value)
{
    Debug.Log(value);
}
```

Также в методе старт в скрипте зомби написано:

```
void Start()
{
    Observer.OnGivePoints += GivePoints;
}
```

Вроде всё сделал правильно, но в строке `Observer.OnGivePoints != null` ругается на `OnGivePoints`, пишет: "**The event OnGivePoints only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Observer')**

Использовал паттерн Observer по этому видеоуроку, и код собственно тоже оттуда взял - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwQ16sS8FSs, у него всё работает почему-то

Comment: А зачем у вас событие статическое?

Comment: чтобы везде можно было вызывать его, или я делаю что-то не так? я делал по гайду

Comment: Ну вы про синглтон почитайте - он и так доступен по инстансу - в нем не нужно статического свойства в этом случае.

Comment: но это ведь не решает мою проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Вы вызываете событие в классе зомби, а не в классе Observer.

Т.е. у вас ошибка здесь:

> У меня есть метод Death в скрипте зомби:

```
public void Death()
{
    if (Observer.OnGivePoints != null)
    {
        Observer.Instance.OnGivePoints(5);
    }
}
```

В этой строчке Observer.OnGivePoints != null идет вызов события, о чем вам говорится в сообщении об ошибке - что можно только подписаться или отписаться от события (+= or -= ), а проверять его на null нужно в классе Observer.
Т.е. проверка на null и вызов события вам надо перенести в класс, где это событие объявлено, либо объявляйте делегат и событие в классе зомби.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл события заключается в том, чтобы его можно было вызвать только из объекта, в классе которого оно объявлено. А извне можно только подписаться или отписаться от него.

Я так понимаю, после смерти зомби, Вам надо прибавить игроку очки? Тогда будет логичнее создать событие в классе зомби и вызывать его после смерти зомби изнутри этого же класса.

В видео уроке же событие нужно для нанесение врагу урона. Урон наносит игрок, поэтому и объявлено событие в классе игрока. Из класса игрока событие и вызывается.

Comment: я хочу организовать паттерн Observer по этой статье, но как-то не получается - https://habrahabr.ru/post/212055/